# Calling Json Objects With Parameters Passed to Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, logic

I've run into an interesting dilemma- I want to write a function which, given a couple parameters, will return an object/parameter in a JSON response based on the value of another.

Snippet 1 shows a way that I could do it with simple case checking:

```js
function callf() {
  return f("name", "project_id", "sampleName");
}

function f(Where, Return, Is) {
  var options = {
    "option1": "asdf",
    "option2": "asdf"
  }
  var url = "..."
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  for (i in jsonResponse) {
    if (Where == "object1") {
      //Instead of dynamically calling the object, use case testing to call the desired object.
      if (jsonResponse[i].object1 == Is) {
        if (Return = "returnValue1") {
          return jsonResponse[i].returnValue1;
        } else if (Return = "returnValue2") {
          return jsonResponse[i].returnValue2;
        }
      }
    } else if (Where == "object2") {
      if (jsonResponse[i].object2 == Is) {
        if (Return = "returnValue1") {
          return jsonResponse[i].returnValue1;
        } else if (Return = "returnValue2") {
          return jsonResponse[i].returnValue2;
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

However, with doing it the way above, I have to account for every possible object that the json response contains, that would be a pain. I want to find an alternative where I can simply pass the a string representing the object I want to return from a function like the snippet below:

```js
function callf(){
  return f("name","project_id","sampleName");
}

function f(Where,Return,Is){
  var options = {
    "option1":"asdf",
    "option2":"asdf"
  }
  var url = "..."
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  for(i in jsonResponse){
    if(jsonResponse[i].(Where)==Is){
      return jsonResponse[i].(Return);
    }
  }
}
```

How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you're accessing json with `i` variable as key using square brackets,

```
for(var i in jsonResponse){
  if(jsonResponse[i][Where]==Is){
    return jsonResponse[i][Return];
  }
}
```